# What are the "fine" differences in these lines and how not to get confused when thinking about them?

Tags: grammar, differences, present-tense, future

I don't see a team without Messi that reaches the top 3 in the world.(Present)
or
I don't see a team without Messi that can reach the top 3 in the world.(Present with "can")
or
I don't see a team without Messi that will reach the top 3 in the world. (Future)

To my ears they all convey the same meaning so if there is a difference no matter how fine it is pls tell me and how to think of which tense to use while speaking?

Comment: They're all messy.

Comment: I should've added "atleast" before "top 3".

Answer (score 0):

"A team that reaches" and "a team that will reach" mean the same thing in this context, but "can reach" and "will reach" are different. "Can reach" means they have the potential, while "will reach" means they are definitely going to reach the top three, in the hypothetical scenario that the speaker is imagining.

However, they all mean basically the same thing in that sentence.